# Conductor container can't be found. Run `ansible-container build` first

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm trying to use ansible-container but get the below error.

Following this example:-

```
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/getting_started.html#real-world-usage-starting-from-a-working-base-setup

Conductor container can't be found. Run `ansible-container build` first
```

Comment: What was the exact command you ran prior to seeing that error?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same exact error recently when working on a Solr Ansible Container project:

```
$ ansible-container --var-file vars.yml build
Building Docker Engine context...   
Starting Docker build of Ansible Container Conductor image (please be patient)...   
ERROR   Conductor container can't be found. Run `ansible-container build` first
```

To get more helpful output (Ansible Container is pretty quiet by default!), you can use `--debug`:

```
$ ansible-container --debug --var-file vars.yml build
```

Now, when `ansible-container` builds your image (and the Conductor), you'll see real-time output of the build process. With any luck, the last few lines of output should show an error message.

The funny thing is, in *my* case, just running another build with `--debug` (after three failed ones *without*), everything succeeded. Weird. Maybe it'll be the same for you :D

Comment: I had similar experience. After you failed runs and restarts of docker engine it started working.

Comment: Heh, yeah, sometimes it makes me wonder if it's the Docker Engine, Docker for Mac, my ISP, Ansible Container, or cosmic rays that cause these weird and random things.